# Autoscaling metrics for ASP.NET Core rest service

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, prometheus, aws-fargate

I'm deploying my asp.net core service on AWS Fargate and I want to hook up some metrics to listen to for it to automatically scale besides the regular CPU and Memory metrics.

For example the thread pool count going to 10% of maximum should trigger an auto scale, also throttling errors should trigger it as well (if it's not test traffic) although I'm not sure how to do either of these with asp .net core just yet.

What other metrics does your services look at to scale on demand? I am having trouble finding best practices surrounding asp .net core on this.

this is a simple service generating openapi clients with end points clients can hit

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [App Runner](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/app-runner-from-code-to-scalable-secure-web-apps/) for your use case? App Runner is a service that builds on top of Fargate and provides a very opinionated experience for request/response web services class of application. The system autoscale in and out based on connection concurrency (that you can set).

Comment: yeah I've heard of app runner, we already have everything setup though, maybe at a later date we can consider switching, I only need some metrics to scale off of and ways to get them to publish to cloudwatch :) and put on my dashboards in a .net specific way.